# javascript assign function with parameter to a variable

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I am working on a project developed in php and javascript.
I need to define a variable that contains a function and its parameters and call it   only when a specific button is clicked.

```
class Project {

    constructor(data_input) {
        this.data=data_input;
    }

    delete_project() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/project/delete",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(this.dati),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Project Deleted");
                console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
            },
        });
    }
}

$('#delete').on("click", function (e) {
  var p = new Project((JSON.parse(this.dataset.prj)));
  const click_cmd = p.delete_project(p.data);
  document.getElementById('modal-btn-ok').onclick = click_cmd;
}
```

I didn't understand how to assign the function and the associated parameter without immidiatly calling it. In the case above the function delete_project is called without clicking any button.

Thanks

Comment: So you're saying, when a button is clicked, you want to assign a function to an object without calling it?

Comment: you can bind function on button click directly <button onclick="delete_project(params)">Click</button>

Comment: @ChetanSinghal — `onclick` attributes have a bunch of problems (there are reasons that they've mostly dropped out of use since the 90s).

Comment: `const click_cmd = () => p.delete_project(p.data);`

Comment: Konrad! it works perfect! Thanks to you!